# What is the proper way to hand off from one ActionResult method to another and trigger the ActionFilterAttribute each time?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, custom-attributes, actionfilterattribute

I am trying to write some methods in a controller that return ActionResult.  Each one has an Attribute on it that is supposed to run some validation logic before allowing the user to use the method.  While in one method, if I detect a certain situation, I'm trying to hand off the data to another method to finish the processing and return the ActionResult.  What I'm finding is that when doing this, the second method is being entered without the validation happening in the Attribute first.  I'm wondering if this is the wrong way to be passing around control to generate the ActionResult and what I can do to make sure my Attribute is hit every time.  Consider the below example.

```
[SpecialActionFilterAttribute(ValidationRequirement1)]
public ActionResult Index(int id, bool handleWithOtherMethod)
{
    MyViewModelType viewModel = this.ModelRepository.GetModel(id);

    if (handleWithOtherMethod)
    {
        return Index(viewModel);
    }
    Response.StatusCode = 200;
    return View(viewModel);
}

[SpecialActionFilterAttribute(ValidationRequirement2)]
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModelType viewModel)
{
    viewModel.SomeSpecialProperty = "Some special value";
    Response.StatusCode = 200;
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

When I try the above code, things *seem* to execute correctly, but the code in the Attribute is not entered when going from the first ActionResult method to the second.  The whole point of this handoff is to force execution back through the ActionFilterAttribute code when a certain situation is true.  Is this bad form?  What should my approach be?

Comment: You would need `return RedirectToAction(...)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke `RedirectToAction` does not "call" another method, it triggers full 302 redirect  - it does not sound like what OP is looking for.

Comment: Why do you want to do this in two methods? Why not handle custom validation steps in a single Action?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, Yes I know, but it would be required to trigger the filter attribute.

Comment: @StephenMuecke how can I pass the view model in a call to RedirectToAction?

Comment: @bubbleking, You could use `return RedirectToAction(actionName, model)` but you shouldn't if the method is a GET (apart from the ugly url, you could exceed the query string and throw an exception, and if any properties of your model are complex objects or collection, binding will fail. Just pass the ID and get the model again or use Session

Comment: Another problem you have with your second method (apart from the fact it has the same name as the first one) is that the values of your model are added to `ModelState` so setting `viewModel.SomeSpecialProperty = "Some special value";` will be ignored if your using an `EditorFor()` (or `TextBoxFor()` etc) method to generate a form control.

Comment: These comments led me to reconsider my approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abort! This is not a good approach.